# How to get cookies from every request in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest, http, cookies

I have a Spring REST API. It is a something like a middleware - user send request to this app and this app is sending request to other API. Every time I need to get cookie named Ltpa from request to my API. Yes I can do it by `@CookieValue` but I need to add it in every function. I'm searching for something what would be executed every time before any function in REST controller will be executed.

Comment: You say you need to "get" it, but what are you going to *do* with it once you have it? Forward it? In what kind of downstream request specifically? Perhaps [the way Spring does this for OAuth tokens](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth/consumer/filter/OAuthConsumerProcessingFilter.java) might be informative.

Comment: JavaScript script get LtpaToken from browser cookies and send request to my API with LtpaToken. Then I need to forward this cookies to request sending by my API to other API.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried implementing interceptor in your application?
I guess this could possibly help you out to meet the objective.

Comment: I'm not sure so I will ask - can I use interceptors also for edit every request sending from my API?

Answer (score 1):

Spring will provide with the HttpRequest if ask for it in your  Restcontroller

```
@GetMapping('/')
public void doStuff(HttpRequest request ){
          String rawCookie = request.getHeader("Cookie");
```

}

Comment: This is a much more complicated version of the `@CookieValue` solution the OP already rejected.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may be looking for a rest interceptor?

```
public class RestTemplateHeaderModifierInterceptor
  implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(
      HttpRequest request, 
      byte[] body, 
      ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {

        ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
        response.getHeaders().add("Foo", "bar");
        return response;
    }
}
```